Missing Eth after sending to contract - Internal transaction
I saw a YouTube video of how to create a smart contract, after sending 0.2 ETH it was transferred to a different contract through internal transactions.
here is the link for the code and contract
https://pastefy.app/0X9GE64I/raw
https://etherscan.io/address/0x178290180cacc675a2b4ba701c55f8dfe4125edc
Can I edit the code and retrieve funds?

Once contracts are deployed they cannot be modified.

Start function directly transferred your eth to the scammers address, so there is nothing to try to exploit at the contract.
